# Make random numbers less random in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo random numbers in php. I'm using this method below

```
<?php
echo mt_rand(10, 100)." Users Online";
?>
```

It works but my problem is: I want to make the numbers less random when someone refresh the page, for example:

```
11 refresh
12 refresh
10 refresh
40 refresh
42 refresh
40 refresh
38 refresh
```

The code that I use give random numbers, **but I want the random numbers to jump in small numbers but not like jumping from 20 to 100!**

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Errm that would make the numbers not random at all...

Comment: why do you need them?

Comment: If you don't want it to jump around you'll have to use sessions to assign a base random number, then add or subtract a smaller random number to show to that user. So for example, a user comes along and is randomly given a number between 10 and 100. They get 40. That is saved in the user's session. Each time you refresh the page generate a random number between -2 and 2 for example and add it to the base number (40). Thus they will see a random number between 38 and 42.

Comment: Sounds like the epitome of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Judging by your question, it seems like you are trying to lie to users about how many people are using your service?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a session variable to keep track of what the number was.
If there was a number set make the random number +-5 of previous value.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['num'])){
    $num = mt_rand($_SESSION['num']-5, $_SESSION['num']+5);
}else{
    $num = mt_rand(10, 100);
}
echo $num . " Users Online"; 
$_SESSION['num'] = $num;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always change your range on your random number generator to be a smaller range. If you want it to be able to be a little more flexible, you could even replace the 30 and 35 in my example below with variables and calculate the max and min for your random number based on the time if you need it to.

```
<?php
echo mt_rand(30, 35)." Users Online";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion...  Perhaps what you really want is a range of random numbers.  To explain...  You could use a Switch statement to actually deliver the results based on your first random number.  like this:

```
 $i = mt_rand(1, 4);
 $finalRand = 0;
 switch ($i) {
    case 1:
        $finalRand = mt_rand(1, 10);
        break;
    case 2:
        $finalRand = mt_rand(11, 20);
        break;
    case 3:
        $finalRand = mt_rand(21, 50);
        break;
    case 4:
        $finalRand = mt_rand(50, 100);
        break;
}
```

The end result of this routine would be to first randomly choose a number from which to randomly choose a number from a final range.

You can tweak this to get whatever results you want.  But that's the basic idea.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. One user can still get 100 the first time and then 5 the next time you refresh the page

Comment: //shrug...  I was just making a suggestion for making his numbers "less random"

Comment: But you aren't doing that. The numbers are just as random as without this code

Answer (score 1):

**This example eliminates a little bit what you describe in your question, it want jump from 20 to 100 very often but it could happen.**

```
$limit = mt_rand(10,20);
$diff = mt_rand(20,80);
echo mt_rand(mt_rand($limit-$diff>0?$limit-$diff:0, $limit), mt_rand($limit, 
$limit+$diff))." Users Online";
```

You could try it out in [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c882a21d167f5bbac400d326d9a7e7f2acb5ad07)
**The first 1000 results are:**

```
15 Users Online
8 Users Online
11 Users Online
28 Users Online
19 Users Online
27 Users Online
6 Users Online
15 Users Online
17 Users Online
14 Users Online
24 Users Online
16 Users Online
38 Users Online
38 Users Online
9 Users Online
17 Users Online
31 Users Online
44 Users Online
23 Users Online
29 Users Online
14 Users Online
17 Users Online
11 Users Online
21 Users Online
69 Users Online
16 Users Online
28 Users Online
18 Users Online
31 Users Online
20 Users Online
23 Users Online
27 Users Online
25 Users Online
15 Users Online
15 Users Online
12 Users Online
5 Users Online
27 Users Online
15 Users Online
12 Users Online
30 Users Online
18 Users Online
10 Users Online
7 Users Online
19 Users Online
38 Users Online
20 Users Online
17 Users Online
5 Users Online
32 Users Online
17 Users Online
21 Users Online
36 Users Online
36 Users Online
24 Users Online
5 Users Online
20 Users Online
26 Users Online
29 Users Online
56 Users Online
20 Users Online
29 Users Online
26 Users Online
16 Users Online
18 Users Online
21 Users Online
15 Users Online
13 Users Online
52 Users Online
16 Users Online
10 Users Online
34 Users Online
31 Users Online
15 Users Online
31 Users Online
6 Users Online
11 Users Online
37 Users Online
11 Users Online
28 Users Online
15 Users Online
8 Users Online
10 Users Online
43 Users Online
16 Users Online
24 Users Online
31 Users Online
63 Users Online
12 Users Online
20 Users Online
16 Users Online
19 Users Online
19 Users Online
33 Users Online
23 Users Online
24 Users Online
9 Users Online
19 Users Online
16 Users Online
13 Users Online
12 Users Online
8 Users Online
14 Users Online
42 Users Online
40 Users Online
21 Users Online
44 Users Online
22 Users Online
21 Users Online
13 Users Online
62 Users Online
17 Users Online
4 Users Online
10 Users Online
26 Users Online
14 Users Online
37 Users Online
12 Users Online
23 Users Online
11 Users Online
24 Users Online
18 Users Online
15 Users Online
51 Users Online
23 Users Online
58 Users Online
32 Users Online
40 Users Online
12 Users Online
12 Users Online
15 Users Online
12 Users Online
22 Users Online
16 Users Online
17 Users Online
24 Users Online
25 Users Online
20 Users Online
30 Users Online
5 Users Online
18 Users Online
13 Users Online
31 Users Online
25 Users Online
51 Users Online
8 Users Online
12 Users Online
23 Users Online
24 Users Online
16 Users Online
10 Users Online
15 Users Online
31 Users Online
49 Users Online
33 Users Online
3 Users Online
21 Users Online
22 Users Online
30 Users Online
16 Users Online
23 Users Online
3 Users Online
14 Users Online
55 Users Online
19 Users Online
9 Users Online
13 Users Online
5 Users Online
36 Users Online
25 Users Online
8 Users Online
18 Users Online
18 Users Online
19 Users Online
26 Users Online
18 Users Online
23 Users Online
28 Users Online
23 Users Online
11 Users Online
19 Users Online
44 Users Online
56 Users Online
16 Users Online
56 Users Online
11 Users Online
19 Users Online
17 Users Online
11 Users Online
21 Users Online
17 Users Online
48 Users Online
7 Users Online
2 Users Online
44 Users Online
15 Users Online
21 Users Online
7 Users Online
13 Users Online
2 Users Online
6 Users Online
45 Users Online
60 Users Online
12 Users Online
15 Users Online
31 Users Online
28 Users Online
10 Users Online
6 Users Online
13 Users Online
4 Users Online
21 Users Online
32 Users Online
7 Users Online
30 Users Online
14 Users Online
28 Users Online
36 Users Online
31 Users Online
26 Users Online
59 Users Online
31 Users Online
20 Users Online
17 Users Online
32 Users Online
19 Users Online
36 Users Online
28 Users Online
1 Users Online
29 Users Online
71 Users Online
43 Users Online
18 Users Online
30 Users Online
21 Users Online
11 Users Online
18 Users Online
52 Users Online
23 Users Online
17 Users Online
23 Users Online
28 Users Online
29 Users Online
17 Users Online
15 Users Online
10 Users Online
44 Users Online
21 Users Online
26 Users Online
6 Users Online
23 Users Online
12 Users Online
32 Users Online
21 Users Online
33 Users Online
28 Users Online
12 Users Online
6 Users Online
18 Users Online
35 Users Online
16 Users Online
8 Users Online
10 Users Online
23 Users Online
36 Users Online
8 Users Online
7 Users Online
14 Users Online
40 Users Online
39 Users Online
28 Users Online
46 Users Online
25 Users Online
10 Users Online
17 Users Online
10 Users Online
23 Users Online
19 Users Online
25 Users Online
10 Users Online
29 Users Online
16 Users Online
20 Users Online
19 Users Online
13 Users Online
21 Users Online
35 Users Online
23 Users Online
17 Users Online
36 Users Online
31 Users Online
11 Users Online
24 Users Online
6 Users Online
8 Users Online
44 Users Online
14 Users Online
27 Users Online
8 Users Online
14 Users Online
27 Users Online
28 Users Online
8 Users Online
63 Users Online
27 Users Online
21 Users Online
4 Users Online
48 Users Online
10 Users Online
36 Users Online
2 Users Online
44 Users Online
18 Users Online
18 Users Online
23 Users Online
10 Users Online
6 Users Online
43 Users Online
37 Users Online
25 Users Online
66 Users Online
35 Users Online
39 Users Online
10 Users Online
14 Users Online
12 Users Online
16 Users Online
39 Users Online
8 Users Online
15 Users Online
10 Users Online
2 Users Online
8 Users Online
7 Users Online
9 Users Online
28 Users Online
27 Users Online
64 Users Online
30 Users Online
32 Users Online
31 Users Online
54 Users Online
58 Users Online
31 Users Online
36 Users Online
16 Users Online
26 Users Online
24 Users Online
14 Users Online
17 Users Online
31 Users Online
11 Users Online
30 Users Online
17 Users Online
19 Users Online
19 Users Online
32 Users Online
13 Users Online
22 Users Online
11 Users Online
48 Users Online
8 Users Online
39 Users Online
28 Users Online
11 Users Online
7 Users Online
43 Users Online
14 Users Online
12 Users Online
52 Users Online
10 Users Online
26 Users Online
12 Users Online
30 Users Online
8 Users Online
6 Users Online
23 Users Online
8 Users Online
28 Users Online
35 Users Online
17 Users Online
11 Users Online
22 Users Online
20 Users Online
17 Users Online
57 Users Online
13 Users Online
27 Users Online
9 Users Online
35 Users Online
22 Users Online
15 Users Online
39 Users Online
15 Users Online
0 Users Online
11 Users Online
19 Users Online
47 Users Online
34 Users Online
6 Users Online
26 Users Online
10 Users Online
37 Users Online
40 Users Online
25 Users Online
48 Users Online
12 Users Online
3 Users Online
46 Users Online
12 Users Online
14 Users Online
38 Users Online
23 Users Online
19 Users Online
16 Users Online
31 Users Online
51 Users Online
26 Users Online
11 Users Online
18 Users Online
24 Users Online
20 Users Online
8 Users Online
23 Users Online
7 Users Online
11 Users Online
15 Users Online
33 Users Online
20 Users Online
16 Users Online
32 Users Online
21 Users Online
12 Users Online
1 Users Online
23 Users Online
34 Users Online
18 Users Online
15 Users Online
38 Users Online
18 Users Online
13 Users Online
14 Users Online
11 Users Online
24 Users Online
12 Users Online
16 Users Online
37 Users Online
21 Users Online
15 Users Online
14 Users Online
9 Users Online
35 Users Online
30 Users Online
3 Users Online
12 Users Online
16 Users Online
48 Users Online
37 Users Online
34 Users Online
14 Users Online
21 Users Online
42 Users Online
9 Users Online
16 Users Online
46 Users Online
47 Users Online
29 Users Online
25 Users Online
19 Users Online
12 Users Online
55 Users Online
21 Users Online
25 Users Online
19 Users Online
28 Users Online
41 Users Online
31 Users Online
19 Users Online
10 Users Online
38 Users Online
13 Users Online
24 Users Online
20 Users Online
9 Users Online
13 Users Online
13 Users Online
12 Users Online
29 Users Online
11 Users Online
14 Users Online
16 Users Online
20 Users Online
18 Users Online
20 Users Online
32 Users Online
33 Users Online
18 Users Online
65 Users Online
12 Users Online
52 Users Online
25 Users Online
30 Users Online
72 Users Online
3 Users Online
46 Users Online
34 Users Online
14 Users Online
28 Users Online
32 Users Online
14 Users Online
25 Users Online
25 Users Online
52 Users Online
17 Users Online
22 Users Online
43 Users Online
24 Users Online
10 Users Online
40 Users Online
4 Users Online
15 Users Online
11 Users Online
8 Users Online
46 Users Online
27 Users Online
13 Users Online
24 Users Online
38 Users Online
36 Users Online
50 Users Online
21 Users Online
27 Users Online
10 Users Online
15 Users Online
29 Users Online
6 Users Online
71 Users Online
9 Users Online
24 Users Online
11 Users Online
48 Users Online
29 Users Online
5 Users Online
15 Users Online
17 Users Online
39 Users Online
74 Users Online
16 Users Online
7 Users Online
35 Users Online
17 Users Online
22 Users Online
32 Users Online
29 Users Online
44 Users Online
14 Users Online
21 Users Online
68 Users Online
40 Users Online
16 Users Online
15 Users Online
63 Users Online
8 Users Online
25 Users Online
20 Users Online
9 Users Online
52 Users Online
22 Users Online
19 Users Online
14 Users Online
9 Users Online
5 Users Online
17 Users Online
10 Users Online
15 Users Online
27 Users Online
32 Users Online
15 Users Online
44 Users Online
20 Users Online
19 Users Online
26 Users Online
9 Users Online
27 Users Online
48 Users Online
33 Users Online
25 Users Online
6 Users Online
34 Users Online
51 Users Online
9 Users Online
34 Users Online
31 Users Online
23 Users Online
66 Users Online
32 Users Online
22 Users Online
21 Users Online
32 Users Online
23 Users Online
36 Users Online
23 Users Online
75 Users Online
38 Users Online
12 Users Online
48 Users Online
5 Users Online
18 Users Online
32 Users Online
40 Users Online
36 Users Online
36 Users Online
12 Users Online
28 Users Online
26 Users Online
17 Users Online
33 Users Online
13 Users Online
22 Users Online
20 Users Online
26 Users Online
24 Users Online
24 Users Online
69 Users Online
71 Users Online
32 Users Online
27 Users Online
29 Users Online
36 Users Online
10 Users Online
20 Users Online
18 Users Online
12 Users Online
32 Users Online
47 Users Online
21 Users Online
19 Users Online
27 Users Online
25 Users Online
13 Users Online
46 Users Online
32 Users Online
31 Users Online
26 Users Online
68 Users Online
42 Users Online
24 Users Online
69 Users Online
2 Users Online
18 Users Online
13 Users Online
7 Users Online
30 Users Online
6 Users Online
21 Users Online
37 Users Online
13 Users Online
9 Users Online
11 Users Online
24 Users Online
4 Users Online
66 Users Online
42 Users Online
17 Users Online
9 Users Online
65 Users Online
11 Users Online
22 Users Online
17 Users Online
18 Users Online
17 Users Online
62 Users Online
14 Users Online
13 Users Online
22 Users Online
3 Users Online
9 Users Online
45 Users Online
25 Users Online
54 Users Online
37 Users Online
13 Users Online
12 Users Online
15 Users Online
15 Users Online
15 Users Online
42 Users Online
14 Users Online
33 Users Online
4 Users Online
11 Users Online
21 Users Online
16 Users Online
5 Users Online
31 Users Online
40 Users Online
22 Users Online
9 Users Online
14 Users Online
14 Users Online
18 Users Online
8 Users Online
37 Users Online
35 Users Online
21 Users Online
30 Users Online
25 Users Online
16 Users Online
16 Users Online
17 Users Online
16 Users Online
22 Users Online
32 Users Online
34 Users Online
17 Users Online
28 Users Online
18 Users Online
15 Users Online
22 Users Online
13 Users Online
11 Users Online
17 Users Online
18 Users Online
77 Users Online
42 Users Online
19 Users Online
13 Users Online
35 Users Online
22 Users Online
55 Users Online
16 Users Online
22 Users Online
35 Users Online
15 Users Online
56 Users Online
51 Users Online
22 Users Online
35 Users Online
65 Users Online
21 Users Online
10 Users Online
60 Users Online
7 Users Online
8 Users Online
8 Users Online
5 Users Online
22 Users Online
74 Users Online
7 Users Online
29 Users Online
42 Users Online
6 Users Online
34 Users Online
10 Users Online
44 Users Online
12 Users Online
23 Users Online
37 Users Online
17 Users Online
55 Users Online
25 Users Online
7 Users Online
40 Users Online
35 Users Online
41 Users Online
28 Users Online
32 Users Online
30 Users Online
24 Users Online
19 Users Online
29 Users Online
18 Users Online
23 Users Online
26 Users Online
30 Users Online
21 Users Online
12 Users Online
29 Users Online
27 Users Online
18 Users Online
15 Users Online
18 Users Online
39 Users Online
10 Users Online
24 Users Online
34 Users Online
7 Users Online
53 Users Online
44 Users Online
32 Users Online
22 Users Online
52 Users Online
56 Users Online
21 Users Online
6 Users Online
13 Users Online
33 Users Online
11 Users Online
7 Users Online
8 Users Online
42 Users Online
24 Users Online
19 Users Online
14 Users Online
30 Users Online
30 Users Online
37 Users Online
8 Users Online
35 Users Online
16 Users Online
23 Users Online
33 Users Online
34 Users Online
61 Users Online
34 Users Online
21 Users Online
33 Users Online
6 Users Online
46 Users Online
9 Users Online
37 Users Online
33 Users Online
5 Users Online
21 Users Online
62 Users Online
4 Users Online
14 Users Online
30 Users Online
17 Users Online
7 Users Online
40 Users Online
16 Users Online
47 Users Online
5 Users Online
27 Users Online
41 Users Online
17 Users Online
14 Users Online
15 Users Online
31 Users Online
35 Users Online
42 Users Online
12 Users Online
62 Users Online
54 Users Online
44 Users Online
45 Users Online
31 Users Online
59 Users Online
9 Users Online
11 Users Online
20 Users Online
18 Users Online
24 Users Online
23 Users Online
33 Users Online
13 Users Online
8 Users Online
6 Users Online
26 Users Online
5 Users Online
12 Users Online
9 Users Online
24 Users Online
22 Users Online
13 Users Online
19 Users Online
27 Users Online
12 Users Online
26 Users Online
10 Users Online
18 Users Online
19 Users Online
41 Users Online
14 Users Online
4 Users Online
18 Users Online
45 Users Online
5 Users Online
6 Users Online
67 Users Online
16 Users Online
78 Users Online
10 Users Online
31 Users Online
18 Users Online
13 Users Online
53 Users Online
19 Users Online
26 Users Online
11 Users Online
41 Users Online
20 Users Online
26 Users Online
23 Users Online
24 Users Online
21 Users Online
17 Users Online
6 Users Online
30 Users Online
8 Users Online
8 Users Online
10 Users Online
2 Users Online
42 Users Online
21 Users Online
61 Users Online
25 Users Online
18 Users Online
13 Users Online
25 Users Online
22 Users Online
17 Users Online
32 Users Online
19 Users Online
24 Users Online
13 Users Online
33 Users Online
9 Users Online
7 Users Online
11 Users Online
38 Users Online
29 Users Online
19 Users Online
15 Users Online
10 Users Online
11 Users Online
8 Users Online
17 Users Online
42 Users Online
18 Users Online
15 Users Online
12 Users Online
6 Users Online
27 Users Online
24 Users Online
16 Users Online
43 Users Online
46 Users Online
9 Users Online
28 Users Online
54 Users Online
15 Users Online
23 Users Online
12 Users Online
5 Users Online
19 Users Online
21 Users Online
13 Users Online
5 Users Online
31 Users Online
16 Users Online
22 Users Online
36 Users Online
41 Users Online
31 Users Online
15 Users Online
19 Users Online
12 Users Online
42 Users Online
25 Users Online
24 Users Online
6 Users Online
31 Users Online
22 Users Online
34 Users Online
9 Users Online
9 Users Online
11 Users Online
14 Users Online
36 Users Online
42 Users Online
36 Users Online
6 Users Online
19 Users Online
14 Users Online
23 Users Online
20 Users Online
27 Users Online
39 Users Online
46 Users Online
25 Users Online
28 Users Online
14 Users Online
11 Users Online
28 Users Online
33 Users Online
22 Users Online
11 Users Online
27 Users Online
29 Users Online
18 Users Online
16 Users Online
74 Users Online
11 Users Online
15 Users Online
8 Users Online
31 Users Online
9 Users Online
```

Test it for yourself in [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b237aab4fc5116f5a4150344b1b922ff1b9fff80)

**EDIT**
You could work yourself out with the proper results by changing `$limit` and `$diff`.

Comment: This is an awesome way to solve it, I will give it a try too :)

Comment: This code too makes big jumps in the random numbers.  Example from 6 to 45 to 60 and back to 12.

Comment: @Andreas it always brings joy to explain... you could optimize this by setting appropriate `$limit` and `$diff`. Using a session variable does make a lot of sense in order to achieve what  @jason5137715 asked. But... since your answer was based on session variable, i think i had to present something different. In addition what happens if you strictly don't want to use a session variable or just can't?

Comment: @Andreas and never forget the initial description in my answer `This example eliminates a little bit what you describe in your question, it want jump from 20 to 100 very often but it could happen.`

Comment: If you can't use sessions? Why would that be? And even if, then use POST because I don't see how this solves the problem

Comment: @Andreas i think it is better to make something less random without POST or SESSION. Your answer is already accepted. My answer eliminates a bit the probability of having large differences per refresh. That does not mean that it does not have at all.